# How do I get my progress bar to 'progress' with a button click?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, progress

I am trying to create a button that when clicked it will make the progress bar increase.

I have set the bar to a maximum of 100 and every time the button is selected, I'm hoping it will go up by 1/10.

Anyone able to help with this? My progress bar is just called 'progressBar'.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:progressDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView36"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="10"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnGenerate"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnGenerate" />





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_squiz);

    /*Button button =
            (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate);
    MyOnClickListener Listener =
            new MyOnClickListener();
    button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) Listener);*/


    //btnGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate);
    //btnGenerate.setOnClickListener(btnGenerateListener);
    TextView ABshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ABNumber);
    TextView BCshow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BCNumber);
    TextView Ashow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ANumber);
    // btnRand.setOnClickListener(btnRandListener);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int ABrandomNumber = rnd.nextInt(34) + 5; //random number between 5 and 39
    //Toast.makeText(SineQuiz.this, "Rand num: " + String.valueOf(ABrandomNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ABshow.setText("" + String.valueOf(ABrandomNumber));
    int BCrandomNumber = rnd.nextInt(20) + 5; //random number between 5 and 25
    //Toast.makeText(SineQuiz.this, "Rand num: " + String.valueOf(BCrandomNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    BCshow.setText("" + String.valueOf(BCrandomNumber));
    int ArandomNumber = rnd.nextInt(25) + 5; //random number between 5 and 30
    //Toast.makeText(SineQuiz.this, "Rand num: " + String.valueOf(ArandomNumber), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Ashow.setText("" + String.valueOf(ArandomNumber));

   /* button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 10);
                }
            });*/


}



public void setBtnGenerateListener (View view) {
    progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 10);}
/*public View.OnClickListener btnGenerateListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + 10);
    }
};*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sine_quiz, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Sorry I don't know if the code is much help! And ideally, if this button could also generate the random numbers I have above that would be a bonus!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd like to help, but can you provide some code to give us some direction in how to help you?

Answer (score 2):

just set the progress to your progressBar:

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+10);
```

To put it into your click event:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+10);
    }
});
```

Comment: so how do I put this into a button click?

Answer (score -1):

Add this in click listener of button.

```
progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress()+10);
```